# Why can't I get the Inline CSS right (I want Left and Right same line)

Tags: html, css

I'm using a new template and figured out placement of other stuff though I'm fairly new to css.  But one thing I can't work out - I want header to show my site name on left side and place a google ad (728x90) right side - on the same line - i.e. inline.

I have tried making separate  in the header (but headers are block so that is wrong)  then I tried to do it using inline or inline-block, but no matter what I do the google add always comes out directly UNDER the the site name (on left).

I also tried using  but I don't think I'm doing it right, I'm not sure how to use the spam and how to connect it with the css

also one more thing about the CSS is that display is set to block (but I removed the word header and that didn't help

I'm going crazy trying to figure this out... any suggestions, the more clear the better will be most helpful! (please be clear about changes to HTML and CSS) Thanks a million!

I will link all the CSS because other parts may be relevant. (won't let me enclose css even though I'm using control k)

http://worldhelplines.org/pbstyle2.css

HTML

```
<div id="main">
<header>
  <div id="logo">
    <div id="logo_text">
      <!-- class="logo_colour", allows you to change the colour of the text -->
      <h1><a href="index.html"><span class="logo_colour">World Help-Lines</span></a></h1>
      <h2>Hotlines for Kids, Teens & Women</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
```

or visit http://worldhelplines.org/pbindex2.html to see it all

Comment: CSS3 has a nice feature called `flexbox`. Take a look. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Specifically, use a flexbox with three items: the thing to the left, a spacer (which can "grow") in the middle; and the thing to the right.

Answer (score -1):

I can't get at your page; our firewall is acting funny (again). However, some experimentation on my own suggests that

`<span style="float: left">Site Name</span><span style="float: right"><img src="yourpic.png"></span>`

will work.

Answer (score -1):

CSS be like

```
     .row{
        width:100%;
    }
    .siteName{
        float:left;
    }
    .ad{
        float:right;
    }
```

Html like

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="siteName">
        Content
    </div>
    <div class="ad">
        Content
    </div>
</div>
```

[SEE THE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/c4r545va/)

Comment: Why do I need `float: left`, which the default position is to the left anyway?

Comment: In the simple case, the `float: left` isn't needed. However, it's still a good practice in case later a change is made to place the text between two pictures, for example - one pic would get the `float: left`, the text would get `text-align: center`, and the other pic would get `float: right`.

Comment: div is a Block element and "A block-level element always starts on a new line and takes up the full width available (stretches out to the left and right as far as it can)." so if you don't add `float:left` your site name will occupy 100% width.Due to which you cant place you rad in line.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin it is required to float:left your first div. to place add something inline with it. for second div(here ad) iit is not needed to add float:right. you use margin to place it on right.

Comment: @ZPBaloch: Using margin only works if there's a containing `DIV` with a known, fixed width. If the viewport width can vary, and the content with it, floating is the only way to ensure that the content is at the right.

Comment: I basically just worked this out from some site, but this confirmed I was doing it right, so thanks so much, I like you labeled it also so I changed how I had it to include ad and sitename which will make it easier to remember in future editing. Only thing is I did not do the first css (row width 100) do I need that?  It seems to work without it, but is it wrong? Or is there already something else in my CSS that says something similar enough?

Comment: by the way my kid just said she liked the old version of my site better (seriously!?) after all this work... please confirm that I'm not crazy and this version (when complete of course) will be much better than my 1999 looking frames site http://worldhelplines.org/      * but keep in mind the site is aimed primarily at kids & teens